# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?' after null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I want to achieve to make a drawer with different items on it, so I am creating a separate file for the `DrawerItems` and the with the constructor, pass the data to the main file. But I get the following error on the `onPressed` function:

```
"The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'"
```

```
class DrawerItem extends StatelessWidget {
    
      final String text;
      final Function onPressed;
    
      const DrawerItem({Key key, this.text, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: onPressed,
        );
      }
    }
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Change your code to accept a `VoidCallback` instead of `Function` for the `onPressed`.
By the way `VoidCallback` is just shorthand for `void Function()` so you could also define it as `final void Function() onPressed;`

Updated code:

```dart
class DrawerItem extends StatelessWidget {
    
      final String text;
      final VoidCallback onPressed;
    
      const DrawerItem({Key key, this.text, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: onPressed,
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any solution if I want a function with argument in it.For example Textfield function "onSubmitted", because it gives me the error as "The argument type 'void Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?".Any solution for this error?

Comment: @HiteshDanidhariya yes you can simply add it in the brackets, i.e. `void Function(String myString)`

Answer (score 138):

#### Dart 2.12 (Null safety):

Instead of

```
final Function? onPressed; // Bad
```

use

```dart
final void Function()? onPressed; // Good
final VoidCallback? onPressed; // Good
```

Comment: final Function()? onPressed; worked for me , thank you :)

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind it? Or point me some link about this? Thank you.

Comment: @vietstone A `Function` can be anything, like `Function()`, `Function(int)`, etc, which is why with Dart null safety, you should explicitly tell what that `Function` is.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Thank you for your point. But I wonder that, as you say about Function() and Function(int), I think this is a kind of Polymorphism, not really Null Safety :D

Comment: @vietstone Polymorphism is a different thing. `Function onPressed` can be invoked by `onPressed()`, `onPressed(1)`, `onPressed(1, true)` so, you may run into runtime error but `Function() onPressed` can only be invoked by  `onPressed()`. This thing is not particular related to null safety but Dart 2.12.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad yes, just curious about the name of this technique specifically

Comment: short & effective answer... thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

Well that's because `onPressed` inside `FlatButton` is not a normal function its `VoidCallBack` Function.
You can try something like this:

```
final VoidCallBack onPressed;
```

While, you are passing a normal `function` into a `VoidCallBack`

Follow the official doc [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/onPressed.html)

[image]

**Updated Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  _myFunction() => print("Being pressed!");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            DrawerItem(
              text: "Hello Jee",
              onPressed: _myFunction,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawerItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function onPressed;

  const DrawerItem({Key key, this.text, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No, its not that the problem is still using final VoidCallBack onPressed;
But thank you.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, what's your Flutter version? Or can you show me which `function` are you passing as parameter to `DrawerItem`

Comment: my flutter version is 1.22.o, I know its old, but I have to use this one because i have an error with java and it wont work with an updated one.

Comment: Actually your code is fine here, can you show me which type of `function` you are passing as a parameter?

Comment: This is the full code, then iI want to be able to pass it to another file with the constructor

Comment: It's not VoidCallBack. It's VoidCallback. The 'b' is in lowercase.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of

```html
final Function? onPressed;
```

Use

```html
final Function()? onPressed; // add parenthesis in Function
```

Answer (score 7):

Put the parentheses `()` after the keyword `Function` when defining the function.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onPressed; //parenthesis () on function
  final String name;
  const Answer(this.name, this.functionMessage, {Key? key}) : super(key: 
key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
           style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
           primary: Colors.black, // background
           onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
          ),
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Text(name),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 possible solutions for this
**if you aware of data types in dart and null safety**

1st:

add  type  `VoidCallback?`

```
class DrawerItem extends StatelessWidget {
      final String text;
      final VoidCallback? onPressed;
    
      const DrawerItem({Key key, this.text, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key); }
```

**2nd:**

if you are a beginner and don't know much about data type you can use dynamic and let dart compiler handled type for you.

```
class DrawerItem extends StatelessWidget {
          final String text;
          final dynamic onPressed;
    
      const DrawerItem({Key key, this.text, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key); }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you still get this error "The parameter `onPressed` can't have a value of `null` because of its type, but the implicit default value is `null`." after modifying the `onPressed` function, just apply the null safety to fix the problem like this;

```
final VoidCallback? onPressed;
```

This works with `Dart 2.x`

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
VoidCallback? _onPressed
```

instead of:

```
VoidCallback _onPressed
```

it's work for me!

Answer (score 3):

use

```
onPressed: () => delete(),
```

instead of

```
onPressed:delete,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use void Function instead of Function and you can specify you type of your function like this:

```html
void Function(bool) onPressed;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class TaskCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool checkBoxState;
  **final void Function(bool? a)? onChecked**;

  const TaskCheckBox(
    this.checkBoxState,
    this.onChecked, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        value: checkBoxState,
        onChanged: **onChecked**);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Dart Sound null safety (sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0') will make you use:

```
final Function()? onPressed; //make use of parenthesis
```

instead of: `final Function? onPressed;`
or: `final void Function? onPressed;`

Answer (score 1):

If all above solution checked, then refer below code

```
class ManageMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const ManageMenu(
      {Key? key,
      required this.faIcon,
      required this.text,
      required this.onTapFunction})
      : super(key: key);

  final FaIcon faIcon;
  final String text;
  final Function onTapFunction;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onTapFunction,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: faIcon,
        title: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You may wrote wrong syntax as `onTap:onTapFunction` instead of `onTap: () => onTapFunction`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to accept a VoidCallback instead of Function for the onPressed.
By the way VoidCallback is just shorthand for void Function() so you could also define it as final void Function() onPressed;

Comment: Please include code in the standard codes tags

Answer (score 1):

void Function(bool? a)? callback;

Check the screenshot of how void callback bool function work
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
final void Function()? onTapping;
```

or

```
final voidCallback? onPressed;
```

Answer (score 0):

2021: If you have a constructor accepting multiple parameters, you might want to use named arguments to avoid confusion:

Sample: Answer Button Widget

```
class AnswerButton extends StatelessWidget {
    
      late final Function()? submitAnswer;
    
      Answer({injectMethod}) {
        this.selectHandler = submitAnswer;
      }
    }
```

Main

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App Title"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          AnswerButton(injectMethod: _nextQuestion) /* <--- named argument */
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

`dynamic onPressed;`

or

`onPressed;` it will autodetect or set the parameter type as dynamic

instead of:

`VoidCallback onPressed;`

Answer (score 0):

For any `onTap`, `onPressed`, `onChange`, etc. functions which returns **void Function()?**

Always use `() =>` or `() {}` and **then declare your function/functions**...

**For example:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ElevatedButton(
    child: Text(text),
    onPressed: () => anyFunctionCall(), // ONLY SINGLE FUNCTION CAN BE CALLED
  );
}
```

**OR**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ElevatedButton(
    child: Text(text),
    onPressed: () {
      firstFunctionCall(),
      secondFunctionCall(),
      // ... MULTIPLE FUNCTIONS CAN BE CALLED
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are sending the parameter while calling the `DrawerItem`  you should also add a parameter to `Function` like that   `final void Function(new par) onPressed;`