# The argument type 'Function?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?

Tags: flutter, dart

this is the screenshot of my error code

this code my inputpage:

```
  child:  ReusableCard(
    onPress: (){
      setState(() {
        selectGender=Gender.male;
      });
    },
      cardChild: IconContent(icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,label: 'Male',),
      colour: selectGender==Gender.male? activeCardColor:inactivecolor,
    ),
```

and this one other page:onpress function does not work.

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  ReusableCard({@required this.colour,this.cardChild,this.onPress});
  final  Color? colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i provide screesshoot for your better understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?' after null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484113/the-argument-type-function-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-void-funct)

Answer (score 1):

Because the widget's `onTap` is defined as a `void Function()? onTap`, the value needs to be returned to be used (as a callback). So use:

```
onTap: ()=> onPress,
```

You can also define the `onPress` as a `VoidCallback?`, then you just need to:

```
onTap: onPress,
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
final Function? onPress;
```

with

```
final Function() onPress;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  ReusableCard({@required this.colour,this.cardChild,this.onPress});
  final  Color? colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress, // the problem is here 
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Change this to That:

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  ReusableCard({@required this.colour,this.cardChild,this.onPress});
  final  Color? colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap:(){

         --add your on press code here 

},
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace like below.

From

```
onTap: onPress,
```

To

```
onTap: () => onPress,
```

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  ReusableCard({@required this.colour,this.cardChild,this.onPress});
  final  Color? colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, this is the way I solved it:

**Instead of**

```
final Function? onPress;
```

**Use this:**

```
final VoidCallback? onPress;
```