# Flutter onPressed Function

Tags: flutter, function, button

Error in onPressed
Trying to pass onPressed Function but getting Error.

Error - The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'. [image]

```
class CircleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CircleButton({required this.icon, required this.onPressed});
  final IconData icon;
  final Function onPressed;                 [![Error][1]][1]//Here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Icon(icon),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        elevation: 6.0,
        primary: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      ),);
  }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?' after null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484113/the-argument-type-function-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-void-funct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change Function to VoidCallback**

```
class CircleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CircleButton({required this.icon, required this.onPressed});
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;   //Change Function to VoidCallback
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Icon(icon),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        elevation: 6.0,
        primary: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `Function` type is actually a `dynamic Function` type.

The `ElevatedButton` expects a `void Function` to its `onPressed` method, which there is actually a type that is a `typedef` for it: `VoidCallback`

So, replace your `Function onPressed` with `VoidCallback onPressed`.