# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool)?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
 Widget _buildSwitchListTile(
     String title,
     String description,
      bool currentValue, 
      VoidCallback updateValue) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      value: currentValue,
      title: Text(title),
      subtitle: Text(description),
      onChanged: updateValue,
    );
```

Comment: Does ['Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64484113/10157127) answer your question

Comment: Im  a beginner and i couldn't find my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

final void Function()? onTap;

and if you want, that function passed some data, you can use it like this:

final void Function(bool)? onTap;

Answer (score 0):

`SwitchListTile` `onChanged` provide a nullable bool on callback.
Try changing `Function(bool) updateValue`

```dart
 Widget _buildSwitchListTile(
     String title,
     String description,
      bool currentValue, 
      Function(bool) updateValue) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      value: currentValue,
      title: Text(title),
      subtitle: Text(description),
      onChanged: updateValue,
    );
```

Comment: glad to help, you can check more about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)  and  find more about [SwitchListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SwitchListTile-class.html)