# SetState isnt defined in StatefulWidgt

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Am trying to change the color of my container using the setState Method  in onPress
but the app crashes with an error of setState isnt defined.And i want to ask for help.Any help provider will be appreciated.Thank you

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'AllContainers.dart';
import 'ColumnContainer.dart';
import 'AllConstants.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

enum AgeStatus { child, old }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  AgeStatus? ageStatus;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Practising_Cards'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: AllContainers(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        ageStatus = AgeStatus.child;
                      });
                    },
                    colors: ageStatus == AgeStatus.child
                        ? activeColor
                        : deactiveColor,
                    mycard: MyColumnItems(FontAwesomeIcons.mars, 'FEMALE'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: AllContainers(
                    colors: ageStatus == deactiveColor
                        ? activeColor
                        : deactiveColor,
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        ageStatus = AgeStatus.old;
                      });
                    },
                    mycard: MyColumnItems(FontAwesomeIcons.mars, 'FEMALE'),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the Container class

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'NewMain.dart';

class AllContainers extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colors;
  final Widget mycard;
  final Function onPress;

  AllContainers(
      {required this.colors, required this.mycard, required this.onPress});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress(),
      child: Container(
        child: mycard,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colors,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried creating a function with the `setState` in it in the State and passed the function to my onPress method and that also didnt work.

Comment: Perhaps [The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64484113/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

AllContainers' property `onTap` has type `Function`.

But I think your intention is `VoidCallback` type.

So, you have to change the type of `onTap` property from `Function` to `VoidCallback`

And you have to pass not `onPress()` but `onPress`.

```
class AllContainers extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colors;
  final Widget mycard;

  // final Function onPress;
  final VoidCallback onPress;

  AllContainers({
    required this.colors,
    required this.mycard,
    required this.onPress,
  });

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // onTap: onPress(),
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: mycard,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colors,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use   `final VoidCallback onPress` inside your `AllContainers` instead of `final Function onPress`
this is the class you should use to solve your problem.

```
class AllContainers extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colors;
  final Widget myCard;
  final VoidCallback onPress;

  const AllContainers(
      {super.key,
      required this.colors,
      required this.myCard,
      required this.onPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colors,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: myCard,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please note that to use annotations and use camelCase in your coding.
happy coding...

Comment: you're welcome dear Emmanuel, I'm here for explaining your problem without any expectation.we should help each other in programming world not having bad competition. happy coding my friend.